# R error reprojecting from EASE 2.0 to WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I have a data file which is in the EASE 2.0 grid (EPSG:6933) which read in with `raster` looks like so:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3000, 3000, 9e+06  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 6000, 6000  (x, y)
extent      : -9e+06, 9e+06, -9e+06, 9e+06  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : /Users/user/Documents/SERDP/FT_ESDR_PER_sort/AMSR_36V_CO_FT_2002_day153_NH_06km.tif 
names       : AMSR_36V_CO_FT_2002_day153_NH_06km 
values      : 0, 255  (min, max)
```

and it plots fine.

I need to get this file in WGS84 though and I am trying to use `projectRaster`.

```
projectRaster(EASE2_raster, crs = '+init=EPSG:4326', method = 'ngb')
```

but this returns:

```
Error in if (xmn == xmx) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I also tried in Qgis with GDAL warp but the output is not correct, is this some problem with the source EPSG maybe?

Comment: (comment posted as answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see exactly why it's happening, but (I'd bet) you can fix with

```
`projectRaster(EASE2_raster, 
to = raster(extent(-180, 180, 0, 90), res = 1, crs = "+init=epsg:4326"))`
```

set the extent and dimension properties of the target (`to`) raster to suit, rather than relying on auto-tools (as with `crs`).

Finally, reprojecting good projected data into longlat is *destructive*, so it's not really a great idea - there are other ways to do it if you want to ask about what you're going to do it for.

Comment: Yes, I know it is destructive, I am sending to google earth engine though and they do not accept EASE 2.0 grid, so I have to re-project, I suppose I could use a different grid besides WGS84 though.